# Scroll view is not coming in listview when using grid height auto

Tags: xaml, listview, grid, uwp-xaml

I want to dispaly controls as in the code. But when listview reaches height of screen, the scroll view is not displaying. How to correct it? Please suggest.

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="ItemListView" Grid.Row="0"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Width="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNum}" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"  Width="50"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        <Border Background="Green"  x:Name="Bg" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="Bg_TappedAsync"  Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock x:Uid="txt_string Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>             
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ScrollViewer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer) will take effects when the content of `ListView`  extend beyond the bounds of the viewport. But in your code snippet, the height of the first row is set to `Auto` which means that the object should be sized to the available size in layout, so that the first row will size to fit its content. And the `ListView` is in this row, in that case, the `ListView` will always have enough space to display the records that the `ScrollViewer` has no need to show. More details please reference [Height and Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml#layout-properties-and-panels).

You have several ways to resolve this, for example,

- Set a fixed size for the `ListView`.
- Set a fixed size or star size for the first row of the `Grid` as follows.

  ```
  <Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <ListView
       x:Name="ItemListView"
       Grid.Row="0"
       Width="Auto"
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>             
         ...
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   <Border
       x:Name="Bg"
       Grid.Row="1"
       Background="Green"
       Tapped="zolioBg_TappedAsync"
       Visibility="Collapsed">
       <TextBlock
           x:Uid="txt_string"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Foreground="White" />
   </Border>
  </Grid>
  ```

Update

> when listview have very less number of item to show(say two rows only) that textbox height need to fill the remaining place of screen (below listview). how can achieve

You must have a way to limit height for the `ListView` to ensure the `ScrollViewer` can work, otherwise `ScrollViewer` will not know how to scroll your items. If you want the height of `ListView` is auto to fit the item counts, as well as the `ScrollViewer` can work, you could consider to set a `MaxHeight` for the `ListView` to determine when the `ScrollViewer` begin working.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions> 
<ListView
    x:Name="ItemListView"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Width="Auto"
    MaxHeight="800"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

Comment: I tried it. scrolling works.but have an issue. when listview have very less number of item to show(say two rows only) that textbox height need to fill the remaining place of screen (below listview). how can achieve it?